# Strange behavior of python built in hash function

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I was playing around with the built-in functions when I came across the hash function. hash function basically returns an integer that is not equal for two different objects as mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#hash). So I tried it with the interactive console and to my surprise the hash values of -1 and -2 are returned same.

If so then how can we use them both in a dictionary as keys (because for a key to be used in dict its hash value must be unique, right)?

```
>>> hash(-1) == hash(-2)
True
>>> hash(-1)
-2
>>> hash(-2)
-2
```

Comment: Dictionaries use the hash to check which "bucket" they should look in for the key, *then* check actual equality to ensure they pick the right item out of the bucket (as there may have been hash collisions).